# Call JS Function from asp.net page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

so i have a js function that calls a web method on my server,my question is:
can this function be called from an as.net button with a parameter from the server?
because that snippet of code that i got from here basically calls my web method as i want,but i dont know how to call this function from my asp.net code and asp.net button

```
 <div>
        <div id="messages">
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="echo" /><input id="echoSubmit" value="Echo!" type="button" />
    </div>



    <%-- JAVASCRIPT --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#echoSubmit').click(function () {
            var mes = $('#echo').val();
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ message: mes });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ARCAProductsCheat.aspx/SendMessage",
                data: jsonText,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#messages").append(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You probably want to look into the OnClientClick event of the asp:button

Comment: my main button runs on server,i want to trigger that function when im inside of my button after i do some stuff i want to call it

Comment: Please add your aspx code